# Java registration simple checker

Tags: java, passwords

I have a simple password and text area checker for a registration page. Here all the text area MUST be filled, otherwise a popup JOptionPane. AND the password and the re-entered password (confirm password) should be equal otherwise warning.

I don't know how to do this.

Code:

```
    private boolean check()  {
    boolean isEmpty=false;

    if(nickNametxt.getText().equals("") || pwdTxt.getText().equals("") || 
      logintxt.getText().equals("") || rePwdTxt.getText().equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill all the fields before proceeding");
    if (pwdTxt != rePwdTxt){ 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Password");
    }
    isEmpty = true ;
    }

    return isEmpty ;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure it is clear what you're actually stuck on. Would you clarify, by editing the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code snippet. The second if condition has been modified from != to .equals as != will verify object reference.

```
private boolean check(){
    boolean isEmpty = false;
    String nickName = nickNametxt.getText();
    String login    = logintxt.getText();
    String pwd      = pwdTxt.getText();
    String rePwd    = nickNametxt.getText();

    isEmpty = true;
    if(!((null != nickName && !nickName.isEmpty()) && (null != login && !login.isEmpty()) 
            && (null != pwd && !pwd.isEmpty()) && (null != rePwd && !rePwd.isEmpty()))){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill all the fields before proceeding");
        isEmpty = true;
    }else if(!pwd.equals(rePwd)){ 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Password");
        //Depending on your usecase - place it here or not
        //isEmpty = true;
    }
    return isEmpty;
}
```

Comment: its still not checking the password to the re-entered password

Comment: I have modified the condition, you may give it a try. If it does not work - please explain with more details by verifying what are the supplied information for these variables.

Comment: the variables are user entered values from a GUI using a Text Field                "Check" is a constructor used/checked first when the button is pressed

Comment: First condition verifies for any field left blank, and only it passes, the pwd.equals(rePwd) condition needs to be verified. So I moved out the 2nd if condition as else if. I tested the same and it worked for me, by just hardcoding values.